# switch statement using array keys and array values?

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a script that shows every *value* in *array keys* using `switch statement` here's my simple code:

```
<?php
$char = array('A'=>'01', 'B'=>'02', 'C'=>'03', 'D'=>null);

foreach($char as $letter => $number) 
{
    switch($char[$letter]) 
    {
        case 'A':
            echo $number;
            break;
        case 'B':
            echo $number;
            break;
        case 'C':
            echo $number;
            break;
        case 'D':
            echo $number;
            break;
        default:
            echo 'LETTER '.$letter.' is empty';
    }
}
?>
```

PROBLEM:

> It won't print the values that has been stored in the *array*.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

> if *A* exist return *01* . . . . . . . and so on. But if the *array key* contains an empty value it returns **'LETTER D is empty'**

any help please? thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use  `switch($letter)`  instead of `switch($char[$letter])`. PHP foreach loop splitted your array as *$letter=>A* and *$number=>01*

```
    $char = array('A'=>'01', 'B'=>'02', 'C'=>'03', 'D'=>null);

    foreach($char as $letter => $number) 
    {
        switch($letter) 
        {
            case 'A':
                echo $number;
                break;
            case 'B':
                echo $number;
                break;
            case 'C':
                echo $number;
                break;
            case 'D':
                if($number=='' || is_null($number)){ 
                  echo 'LETTER '.$letter.' is empty';
                }else{
                  echo $number;
                }
                break;
            default:
                echo 'LETTER '.$letter.' is empty';
        }
    }
```

OR

```
    $char = array('A'=>'01', 'B'=>'02', 'C'=>'03', 'D'=>null);

    foreach($char as $letter => $number) 
    {          
        CheckNumber($letter, $number);                
    }


    function CheckNumber($letter, $number){         
        if($number=='' || is_null($number)){    // add whatever condition you want to check     
            echo 'LETTER '.$letter.' is empty';             
        }else{              
            echo $number;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it won't return 'LETTER D is empty.

Comment: combine case `D` with the `default:` \n `case 'D':` \n `default:` \n `echo 'LETTER '.$letter.' is empty';`

Comment: @Destiny Updated answer, Can you please check

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> `switch($char[$letter])  as switch($letter)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the value inside that array index, not the index. Try this.

```
switch($letter) 
    {
        case 'A':
            echo $number;
            break;
        case 'B':
            echo $number;
            break;
        case 'C':
            echo $number;
            break;
        case 'D':
            echo $number;
            break;
        default:
            echo 'LETTER '.$letter.' is empty';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:** It will give the answer :LETTER D is empty (Default only execute only when no condition is satisfied , if you want to output "letter D is empty" then you have to wrie code inside the letter match case. Here , case D match but there is only code to echo number and there is no number assign for D in array , so t shows nothing. )

```
$char = array('A'=>'01', 'B'=>'02', 'C'=>'03', 'D'=>null);

foreach($char as $letter => $number) 
{
    switch($letter) 
    {
        case 'A':
           if($number==null)
           {
            echo "LETTER ".$letter."is empty";
            }
           else
           {
           echo $number;
            }
            break;
        case 'B':
             if($number==null)
           {
            echo "LETTER ".$letter."is empty";
            }
           else
           {
           echo $number;
            }
            break;
        case 'C':
             if($number==null)
           {
            echo "LETTER ".$letter."is empty";
            }
           else
           {
           echo $number;
            }
            break;
        case 'D':
            if($number==null)
           {
            echo "LETTER ".$letter."is empty";
            }
           else
           {
           echo $number;
            }
            break;
        default:
            echo 'LETTER '.$letter.' is empty';
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a chain :( i don't like my script to be so long

Answer (score 0):

```
       /// This is what I did ... 

         $i = (isset($somevalue))? $somevalue : NULL;  /// where $somevalue could be GET or POST ..or whatever
         $x = array(NULL=>'','monkey'=>'brown','baseball'=>'round','key3'=>'value3');

         $x['brisket'] = 'good'; // if you wanted to add another value...
         $x['pickles'] = 'notSoGood'; // if you wanted to add another value...

        /// uncomment below to view your array values
         // echo '<pre>';
         // var_dump($x); 
         // echo '<pre>';

            switch($i){
                case $i: 
                echo 'my value'.$x[$p];  
                //include_once $x[$p];    
                break;

                default: 
                echo 'default value';   
                //include_once $somedefault;
          }
```